# How to query a Mongo collection from inside of the its own Schema method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In this method, I want to generate a random username for my users when users register. And, I need to check if the generated username is already in use or not.

So, I need to query the 'User Collection'. **I couldn't find how to query User Collection from inside of its method.**

`this.` key, `mongoose.Collection` or `UserSchema` always ends up with this error;

```
TypeError: mongoose.Collection.find is not a function
```

My UserSchema is something like this;

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'name can not be empty'],
        default: ' '
    },
    publicUsername: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

And finally, the method;

```
UserSchema.methods.generateRandomUserName = async function(){
    // Generate a random username
    
    // Find if username already is in use. But, how???
    let user = await mongoose.Collection.find({ publicUserName: username })
    if(user){
        // Generate again if username is in use
    }
    
    this.publicUsername = username
    return username
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the collection through `mongoose.model()`:

```
UserSchema.methods.generateRandomUserName = async function(){
    
    const user = await mongoose.model('User').find({ publicUserName: username })
    // rest of your code
}
```

See this example in the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods